# How do I customize my wordpress blog have darker fonts? Right now I'm using a good theme, except for that

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, customizing

I have a blog in wordpress, and it uses a theme that I like called "Penscratch2".   The only problem is that the default font is somewhat gray.   Is there a way to darken it a little?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme you are trying to edit doesn't support many options for different colors but you can always edit the colors yourself with a little bit of code. Going into the customizer [Dashboard > Appearance > customize] you should have access to the option for "Additional CSS" - once there, you can input the CSS selector and change the color - This is a bit tedious as you need to input each selector and then change to your preferred color, but all elements with the same selector will be affected

To find the selector of an element that you would like to change, you can right-click on the element (text, heading, link, etc.) and click on "inspect" (a menu will pop up and your selected element should be highlighted). An element's selector is contained within a set of <> brackets, usually the first item after the opening bracket(<)

The customizer works with a live preview, so making any changes should show up before you click to publish any changes. Play around with some colors that you like - you can use basic color names like "red" or "blue", rgb/rgba values work as well as hexadecimal values

some common selectors that you'll most likely want to change may include headings (h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6), paragraphs (p) or links (a) - of, course there are many more and it depends on what you're looking to change

Some example code:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
color: red;
}

p{
color: #4b3fc0;
}

a{
color: rgb(75, 188, 79);
}
```